# Inline input type="submit" buttons seem to overlap onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

On the following example page:

http://thevioletvixen.com/authentic-corsets/flowered-brocade-curves-green/

I have the "BUY NOW" and "SIZING HELP" buttons contained within the following code:

```
<div id="container">
   <div style="float: left; width: 20%; margin-top: 5px; margin-right: 10px;">    
       <input type="submit" class="btn add-to-cart AddCartButton" value="BUY NOW" />
   </div>    
   <div style="float: right; width:20%; margin-top:5px;">
        <input type="submit" class="btn add-to-cart AddCartButton sizingHelp" value="Sizing Help" onclick="AddShoppersWidget.API.User.track('Find_size_btn_clicked'); window.location.href='http://thevioletvixen.com/sizing-help/';">
   </div>
</div>   
<div class="clear"></div>
```

However, when one tries to click on the "SIZING HELP" button the error message for the "BUY NOW" button is displayed because no size or options have been selected.

How can I have this interference error?  I'm try to hack this solution so there might be a better way to get the buttons inline with each and not contained within one div, if that's causing the problem?

Thanks for all help and suggestions.

Comment: You're probably listening in for a cllick on event on a class that is present in both buttons. Why are there `add-to-cart AddCartButton` classes on both links?

Comment: There is not HTML/CSS problem from what I see, something to do with JS

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your post (not an entire program or webpage).

Comment: You must edit your question and show your JS or jquery code, because you have that message near to ....  $(function(){ $("#62e854e6efdeb7b6ee08095d269553ec") .....

Comment: @BoulderJoe Does my answer help? If it does, then please accept. If not, then what didn't work? And good luck here at SO!

Answer (score 0):

Like @MaxMastalerz said in his comment, you probably have a `click` event on both buttons.

For example, if you have something like:

```
$(".add-to-cart").click(function() {
    if(/* no size or options have been selected */) {
        alert("Error: No size or options have been selected.");
    }
});
```

Make sure to look for your event listener for the click, and see what is triggering it (i.e., is it something like `$(".add-to-cart")` or `$(".btn")`, because these are present in both buttons?) and make sure to make it specific to the "Buy Now" button.

Hope this helps!

**Edit**: And as @AdityaPonkshe said in their comment, it's not an HTML / CSS error. Making the buttons inline will not have anything to do with their click events.